# How do I make a Capybara Rails TestCase run as a single transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, minitest

I have a rails app that includes a blog feature.

In one single feature test (using Capybara::Rails::TestCase, with ruby tests (asserts/refutes) i.e, not spec) for the blog, I want to test adding a post, adding comments, editing the post, etc. as individual tests - each of these tests builds upon the last one, as the post created in the first test is commented on in the second test, and so on.

I have seen posts which show workarounds for doing this in a unit test (global variables, use setup/teardown), but I wondered if there is a more direct way to do it in a feature test, since it is likely more common here.

Ideally, I want the login session to persist, as well as database records created in previous tests to persist across each test in the TestCase. Setup and teardown could be used to login each time, but not the intermediate records created for posts, comments, etc.

I want something like:

```
class BlogTest< Capybara::Rails::TestCase
  test 'can sign in' do
      user = User.create!(name: "user", 
             email: "user@example.com", 
             password: "passw0rd!", password_confirmation: "passw0rd!")

      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in('Login', :with => user.email)
      fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
      check('Remember me')
      click_button('Sign in')
  end

  test 'can create post' do
    visit new_post_path # how can I have user logged in?
    fill_in "Title", with: "My first post title!"
    fill_in "Body", with: "My first post body!"
    click_button "Publish"
  end

  test 'can comment on post' do
    visit post_path(Post.first) # should go to post created in last test
    click_button "Add comment"
    ...
  end
end
```

I have heard that this may be possible in Cucumber, but chose not to use Cucumber for other reasons, so want it to work with Minitest and Capybara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Capybara::Rails::TestCase` inherits from `ActiveSupport::TestCase`. One of `ActiveSupport::TestCase`'s main features is that it runs each test in a database transaction. There are ways to work around this, but I would not recommend them.

Instead, I suggest you work with the behavior of the rails test classes. In this case, you want to share actions between tests. I recommend you extract those actions into methods and call those methods in your tests. Here is how I would implement this with your test code:

```
class BlogTest< Capybara::Rails::TestCase
  def user
    @user ||= User.create!(name: "user", 
                           email: "user@example.com",
                           password: user_password,
                           password_confirmation: user_password)
  end

  def user_password
    "passw0rd!"
  end

  def sign_in(email, password)
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in('Login', :with => email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => password)
    check('Remember me')
    click_button('Sign in')
  end

  def create_post(title = "My first post title!",
                  body = "My first post body!")
    visit new_post_path # how can I have user logged in?
    fill_in "Title", with: title
    fill_in "Body", with: body
    click_button "Publish"
  end

  def comment_on_post(post, comment)
    visit post_path(post)
    click_button "Add comment"
    # ...
  end

  test "can sign in" do
    sign_in(user.email, user_password)
    # add assertions here that you are signed in correctly
  end

  test "can't sign in with a bad password" do
    sign_in(user.email, "Not the real password")
    # add assertions here that you are not signed in
  end

  test "can create post when signed in" do
    sign_in(user.email, user_password)
    create_post
    # add assertions here that post was created correctly
  end

  test "can't create post when not signed in" do
    create_post
    # add assertions here that post was not created
  end

  test "can comment on post when signed in" do
    sign_in(user.email, user_password)
    create_post
    post = user.posts.order(:created_at).last
    comment_on_post(post, "I can comment because I'm signed in!")
    # add assertions here that comment was created correctly
  end

  test "can't comment on post when not signed in" do
    post = Post.first
    comment_on_post(post, "I can't comment because I'm not signed in!")
    # add assertions here that comment was not created
  end
end
```

Each action has a good name, and you can reuse those actions for different types of tests. Each test is executed within a database transaction, so each time the each test method is run the database looks the same.

Comment: Perhaps some of these methods could also be added to Capybara::Rails::TestCase in test_helper.rb? Things like user and user_password are useful more generally?

Comment: I posted an extension of your response (to enable layered testing) as a blog post [here](http://rcanand.github.io/How_To_Test_Rails_With_Minitest_And_Capybara/).